# How to get updated data when save_post triggers?

Tags: custom-post-types, save-post

I am running a function to do some stuff when `save_post` triggers to use new data. However, the `$post` object it returns, contains old data of the post, not new data! How can I get new post data inside my function? I have tried `$WP_Query`. But still, same old data!

This is how I am doing this:

```
function my_awesome_func ($post_id, $post, $update) {
    //my stuff
}
add_action( 'save_post_my-custom-post-type', 'my_awesome_func', 10, 3 );
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "use new data"? The save_post_* hook is fired once the the post is saved, but you have to handle anything else manually  - for example saving post_meta

Comment: By "new data" I meant, updated data of post meta. For example: i have one post meta, named "details". Now when I change value of "details" and update post, my function gets old value of "details", not the new set value.

Comment: @Welcher looks like your comment gave me some hint. Do I need to update post meta from my function? Something like this? Do I get data in my function like `$_REQUEST['my-meta-key']`?

Comment: yes that's exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post this as an answer, because it worked for me:

```
function my_awesome_func ($post_id, $post, $update) {
    //update the value we need early
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_meta_key', $_REQUEST['my_meta_key']);

    $newValue = get_post_meta($post_id, 'my_meta_key');
}
add_action( 'save_post_my-custom-post-type', 'my_awesome_func', 10, 3 );
```

You could also simply use the value of $_REQUEST['my_meta_key'] directly if that works, but for my sake I wanted to update the post immediately so I could get the value via another function, not use the value immediately.